# Problemas na remoção em árvore binária de busca em C

Tags: c, estrutura-de-dados, árvore-binária, busca-binária

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês em um código de árvore binária de busca. 
Já tenho todo o código porém estou com problemas na parte da remoção de um nó com um filho. 
Já olhei análises para esse mesmo código no qual me baseei e pelo que que falam, ele deveria funcionar mas aqui isso não acontece. O problema é o seguinte: supondo que eu queira remover o nó que possui o número 9 e tenha apenas um filho à sua direita de valor 10 e que seu pai seja o 8. A representação ficaria mais ou menos assim: 8->9->10. Para remover o 9, temos que fazer o 8 apontar para o 10 e liberar a memória do 9. Porém, tentei reescrever o código algumas vezes e tive duas situações distintas: 
1ª) Nada acontece. Na hora de imprimir a árvore após a remoção do 9, ele continua lá: 8->9->10;
2ª) O 9 é removido mas aparecem dois números, 0 e 1, no seu lugar. Ficando assim: 8->1->0->10.

Por conveniência, eu considero que "aux = *raiz", sendo a raiz a própria raiz da árvore e o "ant" recebe o valor do aux na posição que queremos remover, no caso, o 9.

Eis a versão do código para a primeira situação:

```
                aux = aux->dir;
                aux->dir = NULL;
```

Sei que neste caso o 9 continuará ocupando espaço na memória, porém acredito que apesar disso ele não deveria mais aparecer na hora de imprimir a árvore.

Eis a versão do código para a segunda situação:

```
                aux = aux->dir;
                aux->dir = NULL;
                free(ant); 
                ant = NULL;
```

Não sei se isso afeta em algo, mas eu escrevo o código no Sublime e compilo usando o GCC na linha de comando do Ubuntu 20.04

Caso achem necessário, posto o restante do código. Mas acredito que esteja funcionando nas outras partes dele.